# os.path.isdir return false for directory with dot on end

Tags: python

Windows 7, python 2.6.6, 2.7

Create directory 'c:\1\test.'

Try check if it is dir or file, but it is neither:

```
>>> os.listdir('c:/1')
['test.']
>>> os.path.isdir('c:/1')
True
>>> os.path.exists('c:/1/test.')
False
>>> os.path.isdir('c:/1/test.')
False
>>> os.path.isfile('c:/1/test.')
False
```

Why directory with . at end not recognized as file system entry at all? But I can obtain it from os.listdir.

Comment: Can't reproduce. How did you create this directory? My Windows 7 (32 bit) strips the dot, no matter whether I use `mkdir` or the explorer, I always end up with `test`. `os.listdir` confirms this (`['test']`). `os.isdir` returns `True` for both `test` (and for `test.`, presumably because the dot is stripped there as well) and `os.isfile` returns `False` as expected.

Comment: I am create it with Far. Also it can be created with cygwin/mkdir.

Comment: Windows has problems with such filenames in general. For example, you can't navigate into the directory or delete it in Explorer.

Comment: I see... So, I think this is not problem for my program. Users usually can't create such directories, only geeks like me :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was said in the comments, on Windows, file names that end with a dot, begin/end with spaces, are "aux", etc. etc. etc. - cannot be accessed normally from explorer or from most programming languages.

If you do want to access directories such as "test." from python (or other) code, you can prefix the path with `\\?\`, for example:

```
>>> os.path.isdir(r"\\?\c:\1\test.")
True
```

Note that ".." and "." will not work as usual when using `\\?\` paths - windows will try to access an actual file or directory with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double backslash (\\) to escape the dot in the path,
this is a well-known problem with the use of special characters in the file name or path to it

```
path = 'c:/1/test\\.'
```